# Solving a problem that is function of vector (norm 1)

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Assume we have a vector ${\bf v}$ of complex entries and we are trying to solve for the following

$$ \text{Re} ({\bf v} ^H e^{ j \text{angle} ({\bf v})})=?$$

where $\text{Re}$ means the real part of imaginary number and angle$(\bf{v}$) denotes the phasor vector of ${\bf v}$ (a vector of phase of each element within ${\bf v}$) and supercript $H$ is conjugate transpose. I have seen that the solution (presented in a published paper) is

$$ ||{\bf v}||_1$$

that is norm one of the vector is the solution where norm one is $\sum_i |v_i|$

I am trying to find out why, I understand the phase is gone, but why is it that the solution is norm 1

$$ \text{Re} ({\bf v} ^H e^{ j \text{angle} ({\bf v})})=\text{Re} (? \,e^{ -j \text{angle} {\bf v}} e^{ j \text{angle} ({\bf v})})$$

Thanks

Comment: What is angle$(\mathbf{v})$?

Comment: Sorry, I will edit.